# Is there an application Called Bluetooth Manager in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, toshiba-laptop

Every time I shutdown Windows 10 and restart it, I get the following message:

[image]

I'm afraid of its being as Malware. I tried to search for that application "Bluetooth Manager", but I could not find it.

In addition, I tried to turn on Bluetooth by pressing FN + F12 (My computer is Toshiba Satellite L850) to turn on Bluetooth but I could not find any Bluetooth icon in system tray.

I'm using Avast antivirus and it does not give any warning about any Malware.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth manager in windows 10 is how you connect to assorted bluetooth devices. If its giving you a message when you try to shut down it is because you are currently still connected to a device. Search "bluetooth" in your windows search panel, then check if you are connected to any devices. If not try turning bluetooth off then restarted to see if you get the same message. Hope this helps.